# Как опубликовать в сети сайт, написанный на apache + html + vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, html, apache, публикация-приложений

Я написал сайт, используя только html, CSS и JavaScript (без фреймворков, без базы данных).

На страницах сайта размещена примитивная текстовая игра и пара специфических калькуляторов (то есть предполагается не разглядывание статичных страниц, а постоянное взаимодействие пользователей с программой).

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, как лучше разместить его в Сети?

Я установил было Apache, но теперь не понимаю, что с ним делать: авторы видеоуроков и форумов упорно рассказывают о php, который я не использовал. Попытки гуглить варианты публикации сайта привели лишь к тому, что я быстро потерялся в предлагаемых вариантах

Поскольку web-программированием занимаюсь без году неделю, дело осложняется незнанием специфической терминологии (особенно сленгов).

Подскажите, пожалуйста, алгоритм публикации сайта для человека, который столкнулся с проблемой впервые: просто опорные пункты, чтобы я понимал, куда гуглить, вроде "установить Apache - настроить *** - зарегистрироваться на *** - оплатить *** - обновлять, используя ***..."

Comment: В текущем случае просто идёшь на хостинг, хоть беспланый, и заливаешь туда всё. Больше ничего не надо.

Comment: Используйте любой вам подходящий хостинг из поиска, смотрите по тарифам\ценам\условиям, как правило, на каждом хорошем хостинге есть подробные инструкции как и что делать, в целом вам просто нужно загрузить файлы сайта на хостинг и всё будет работать. Домен можете купить отдельно, либо воспользоваться предложением хостинга (некоторые дают его в подарок)

Comment: Возможно вам хватит обычного GitHub Pages?

Answer (score 1):

Думать про апач тебе не нужно.

Нужно купить (арендовать) хостиг и домен.
Далее на хостинге завести этот домен и у регистратора домена направить его на хостинг (прописать нужные NS).
Залить на хостинг свои html/js/css файлы и радоваться.

PS. Если не интересует раскрутка и трафик, то можно найти бесплатный тариф хостинга и даже домен 3-го уровня.